# A word that can refer to a finger?

Tags: numbers

A digit is single symbol that tells how many.It’s also a word that can refer to a finger(another way to show how many)

A word that can refer to a finger? Like one finger ? Two fingers,etc?

Comment: Have you looked up _digit_ in a dictionary?

Comment: *Digit* meaning finger has no functional relationship to *digit* meaning number.  The normal rules for forming plurals is applied.  One/A finger = One/A digit.  More than one finger = fingers = digits.

Comment: Each hand has four fingers and one thumb, or five digits.

Comment: No  functional relationship? You just sad one/ A finger=one/A digit.What is a no functional relationship?

Answer (score 2):

I think there's some misunderstanding in the second definition.

> It’s also a word that can refer to a finger (another way to show how many)

This definition of digit *is the same as* finger (or toe, they're digits too). It's not a word that shows how many fingers. Here are some sample sentences:

> He lost a digit working with a table saw *(he cut off a finger probably, or maybe a toe if he was sawing very strangely)*
> Frostbite can damage the digits before the rest of the feet or hands *(the large parts of the hands and feet can stay warmer than the fingers and toes)*